# why is that my jquery dialog wont pop out?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I don't know what is wrong why my dialog won't pop up because when I try pop outing the form from the html it works fine but from with this jquery table generated it won't . So what will i do?

```
success: function(data){
            var toAppend = '';

            toAppend += '<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Image</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>';
            toAppend += '<tbody>';

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                toAppend += '<tr><td><p>'+

                data[i]['product_name'][0]+'</p></td><td><a href="#">'+

                <img id="size" src="'+data[i]['image'][0]+'" alt="">+'</a></td><td>'+

                data[i]['price'][0]+'</td></tr>';
            }

            toAppend += '</tbody>';

            $('.data-results').append(toAppend);
        }
```

here's the calling the dialog function

```
$('#size').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Not if you're looping it's not.

Comment: Ensure you have an element with id `'dialog'` before attempting to call `.dialog(..)` on it.

Comment: posting a fiddle { http://jsfiddle.net } will make it easy for us to see the issue and suggest the correct fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename id="size" to class="size", because parameter "id" must be unique for each element

```
$('.size').live("click",function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an iterator.

```
<img id="size-"+i
```

Change your click selector -

```
$('img[id^=size]').click(function(){ 
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Im a bit confused, I removed the size from id so basically the id turns to 0,1,2 etc... how can I call it?

Comment: You should leave it as it was, and change the `<img` tag's `id` just as I've shown you.

Comment: yes I followed it and from my firebug the id generated is like this <img id="size-0" but still no dialog coming out

Comment: the click function should be inside the loop?

Comment: need to use event delegation for the click event because the images are dynamically added. `$(document).on("click","img[id^=size]", function...)`